# How to set console font to Raster Font, programmatically?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, console

How do I make sure that the command prompt's current font is the default Raster Font, at runtime?
I'm using C++ with WinApi.

For now I've used `GetConsoleFontEx();` and `SetConsoleFontEx();`, but I haven't been able to find the right value for the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX`'s `FaceName` property. I found a few examples online where the font was set to Lucida and/or Consolas, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
COORD fs = {8, 8};
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie = {0};
cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);

GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hOut, 0, &cfie);

char fn[] = "Raster"; // Not really doing anything
strcpy_s((char*)cfie.FaceName, 32, fn); // Not sure if this is right
cfie.dwFontSize.X = fs.X;
cfie.dwFontSize.Y = fs.Y;

SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hOut, 0, &cfie);
```

I have tested the return value of `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`, and it's non-zero, indicating a successful call. The font does not change, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adapting the [MS example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`, this seems to work. Note that when the cue `Enter` is pressed, the whole console changes font.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** args)
{ 
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof cfi;
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 20;
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    printf("A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n");

    printf("Setting to Lucida Console: press <Enter> ");
    getchar();
    wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);

    printf("Setting to Consolas: press <Enter> ");
    getchar();
    wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);

    printf("Press <Enter> to exit");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answers the question `How to change the font to Consolas or Lucida?`, which I explicitly mentioned to not be interested in. Instead, I'm looking for a way to change the font to the _Raster Font_, in case the user has set the default font to either Consolas or Lucida.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought the raster font meant the default Windows 7 command prompt font. What I'm talking about is the bitmap font. [Here's](http://benryves.com/tutorials/winconsole/ascii.gif) a table of the characters it has. If you open up the command prompt properties, Font tab, you'll see it listed as "Raster Fonts".

Comment: Try using the font "Terminal"

Comment: Before the two fonts I mention were availabIe in Windows console, I used to use a raster font I installed called `OEM***` something, sorry I cannot find it right now.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I noticed that if I use an obviously invalid value as `FaceName`, it'll set the font to the bitmap font. Though, when I did that, I wasn't able to effectively change the `dwFontSize` anymore. Then I noticed I hadn't set `FontFamily` nor `FontWeight`, like you did, so I tried it. Now it seems to work no matter what (invalid) font name I use. So if I set the font name to "Terminal", it seems to be working. Thank you.

Comment: I found `8514oem.fon` in my archive, it googles for download too.